# Bitmap file header size

Tags: file-format, bmp

I'm a newbie in programming bmp files and i checked this web site to learn about bmp header..
http://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-bmp

it seems that the header of a bmp file is 54 bytes.

Using paint, i created a simple 10x10 image, and i saved it in 24 bits.
so according to simple math, the file size should be 10*10*3 + 54 = 354 bytes.

but hex editor and file explorer returned a size of 374 bytes.

So i have a difference of 20 bytes, and i don't know why.

could you tell me why please?

thanks a lot!!

Comment: Padding for alignment? Use `SizeOf` instead of calculating it yourself. (Also, it helps if you mention the programming language you're asking about; it makes it much easier to provide an answer.)

Comment: Well, he's using MSPaint, not a programming language :)

Comment: @nneonneo: "I'm a newbie in programming bmp files" is the opening sentence of the question.

Answer (score 16):

Lines in BMPs are padded out to multiples of 4 bytes.

Without padding, each line is 3*10 = 30 bytes. With padding, each line is 32 bytes, so the image data is 320 bytes in size. Thus, the file size is 54+320 = 374 bytes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer. That makes sense... but in my program, i have a matrix of 10x10 pixels, each pixel is RGB. So i have an extra of 20 bytes  of raster data to calculate ?  I'm a little bit confused ... thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user1657743: you don't have to put anything specific in the padding; it's just garbage bytes that nobody (except steganographers) will see.